# jQuery, ajax request doesn't success with JSON on IE

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, internet-explorer

I made an AJAX call and it works on FF & Chrome but not on IE 7-8-9. I'm loading a JSON file from my domain:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'js/jquery.desobbcode.json',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function(json) {
            alert('ok');
        },
        error: function(xhr, errorString, exception) {
            alert("xhr.status="+xhr.status+" error="+errorString+" exception="+exception);
        }
    });
```

I also tried by adding `contentType: 'application/json'` but I receive the same output which is :

```
xhr.status=200
error=parsererror
exception=SyntaxError Unterminated string constant
```

I checked my JSON file with [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) and it's OK. I checked if there is an extra comma and the content is also trimmed. [See my JSON file](http://dev.chez-syl.fr/desoBBCode/js/jquery.desobbcode.json)

If I put `dataType: 'text'`, I receive the OK alert but a debug popup too.

Could you help me? Regards.

Comment: Seems to me the problem is with your data type. What mimetype is being used in the response? It should be the same as what the client is expecting. If your response is using a text/html mimetype it will cause the error callback to be called when using dataType: json.

Comment: Which content-type header does `js/jquery.desobbcode.json` emit?

Comment: "If I put dataType: 'text', I receive the OK alert but a debug popup too." - You mean you get an error?  If so what does it say.

Comment: Thank's all, I fixed it, it was just an encoding issue. My JSON file was in ANSI, in Notepad++ I checked "Convert to UTF-8" and it's OK. The contentType wasn't needed in my case.

Answer (score 5):

[IE is known to have issues with implied content types.](http://encosia.com/3-mistakes-to-avoid-when-using-jquery-with-aspnet-ajax/)

> ... the new XmlHttpRequest class in Internet Explorer 7 doesn’t implement setRequestHeader very intuitively. Instead of setting the specified header, it appends the value.

Try specifying a `contentType` and check what's coming back from the server:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'js/jquery.desobbcode.json',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    ...
});
```

You may also want to try sending blank data:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'js/jquery.desobbcode.json',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: {}
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using php script to echo your json as a string just put

```
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
```

before

```
echo $jsonString
```

line.

Answer (score 1):

It's the newlines in the JSON.  This should parse in IE:

```
{"inputButton":[{"id":"desoBBCode_bold","value":"Gras","tag":"b"},{"id":"desoBBCode_italic","value":"Italique","tag":"i"},{"id":"desoBBCode_underline","value":"Souligné","tag":"u"},{"id":"desoBBCode_image","value":"Image","tag":"img"},{"id":"desoBBCode_link","value":"Lien","tag":"url"},{"id":"desoBBCode_quote","value":"Citation","tag":"quote"}],"selectTextSize":[{"text":"Taille","value":""},{"text":"Trèstrèspetit","value":"1"},{"text":"Trèspetit","value":"2"},{"text":"Petit","value":"3"},{"text":"Gros","value":"4"},{"text":"Trèsgros","value":"5"},{"text":"Trèstrèsgros","value":"6"}],"selectTextColor":[{"text":"Couleur","value":"a"},{"text":"Rouge","value":"red"},{"text":"Bleu","value":"blue"},{"text":"Vert","value":"green"}]}
```

Live example: http://jsbin.com/umahiq/edit

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try setting the contentType to "text/json" instead of "application/json". I have had some issues in the past using "application/json" and using "text/json" has always seemed to work better.

Comment: Didn't know such a mime type existed.

Comment: I don't think it actually does, the RFC says application/json is the correct mime, but I've found text/json to work more consistently.